# How to write a general wrapper for calling a Fortran function in C++14 (call by reference --> call by value)

Tags: c++, fortran, c++14

Often I have to call some Fortran routine from my C++ code. In my case, a C header is always available and contains signatures such as

```
double fFortran(int* a, int* b, double* someArray, int* sizeOfThatArray)
```

My question is: Would it be possible to write a generic C++14 wrapper `fortranCall` (maybe using template metaprogramming)
that takes addresses where necessary and then calls the fortran function
like this

```
double someArray[2] = {1, 4};
double result = fortranCall(fFortran, 4, 5, someArray,
    sizeof(someArray) / sizeof(someArray[0]));
```

which should be equivalent to

```
double someArray[2] = {1, 4};
int sizeOfSomeArray = sizeof(someArray) / sizeof(someArray[0]);
int a = 4;
int b = 5;
double result = fFortran(&a, &b, someArray, &sizeOfSomeArray);
```

I think the correct solution involves parameter packs but I can't figure out how to iterate over one and take references where needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this answer I'll make the following assumptions:

- parameters to the FORTRAN functions are all passed as pointers
- the pointer addresses are to be obtained from the parameters passed to the `fortranCall` function.
- Array pointer parameters will always be followed by a pointer to the size of the array
- We want to preserve the order of the parameters.

---

Example calls:

```
// So, given function signature
double fFortran(int* a, int* b, double* someArray, int* sizeOfThatArray);
// we would like to call with:
fortranCall(fFortran, 4, 5, someArray);

// Likewise, given
fFortranTwoArrays(double* arrayA, int* size_of_A, double* arrayB, int* size_of_B);
// we would like to call with
fortranCall(fFortranTwoArrays, someArray, some_other_Array);
```

---

The following program will make the calls as shown above:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

// Functions to call eventually
double fFortran(int* a, int* b, double* someArray, int* sizeOfThatArray)
{ 
    return 0.0; 
}

double fFortranTwoArrays(double* arrayA, int* size_of_A, double* arrayB, int* size_of_B)
{ 
    return 0.0; 
}

// If T is an array 
// then make a std::tuple with two parameters
//   pointer to first of T and 
//   pointer to extent of T
template<
    typename T,
    typename std::enable_if <
        std::is_array<T>{},
        int
    >::type Extent = std::extent<T>::value,
    typename Ptr = typename std::decay<T>::type
>
auto make_my_tuple(T& t)
{
    static auto extent = Extent;
    Ptr ptr = &t[0];
    return std::make_tuple(ptr, &extent);
}

// If T is not an array 
// then make a std::tuple with a single parameter
//   pointer to T
template<typename T,
    typename std::enable_if <
        !std::is_array<T>{},
        int
    >::type = 0 
>
auto make_my_tuple(T& t)
{
    return std::make_tuple(&t);
}

template<typename F, typename... Targs>
auto fortranCall(F& f, Targs&& ... args)
{
    // Make a single tuple with all the parameters.
    auto parameters = std::tuple_cat(make_my_tuple(args)...);

    // Arrays were each expanded to 
    // two pointer parameters(location and size).
    // Other parameters will pass as a single pointer
    return std::apply(f,parameters);
}

int main()
{
    double someArray[2] = {1, 4};
    double result = fortranCall(fFortran, 4, 5, someArray);

    double some_other_Array[] = {6,7,8,9,10};
    auto result2 = fortranCall(fFortranTwoArrays, someArray, some_other_Array);
}
```

---

std::apply is C++17. If you want to make it work in C++14, use the example implementation from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply

```
namespace detail {
template <class F, class Tuple, std::size_t... I>
constexpr decltype(auto) apply_impl(F&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}
}  // namespace detail

template <class F, class Tuple>
constexpr decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, Tuple&& t)
{
    return detail::apply_impl(
        std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t),
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>::value>{});
}
```

and use invoke from the backport by Martin Moene (https://github.com/martinmoene/invoke-lite)

Comment: Thank you, this solution is nice and does most of what I want! However, if I then have  another fortran function `fFortranTwoArrays(double* arrayA, double* arrayB)` which I want to wrap, I would need to write another `fortranCall2` with two array parameters, right?

Comment: I've updated the answer to fulfill the general use case.

Comment: Very impressive, that's exactly what I was looking for! I added some details about how to backport std::apply to C++14 for people who are stuck with it like me.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is promotion, I am actively developing the linked repo.

That being said, the linked project can be used to automatically generate the required `ISO_C_BINDINGS` and C++ header files for what you are asking about.

Me and my research group have forked a project that was "left for dead" ([massive credit to first developer](https://github.com/mcfarljm)), which can be used to automatically generate an `ISO_C_BINDINGS` module for a fortran codebase, as well as generating a C++ wrapper. Additionally, we have automated generation of [`pybind11`](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) bindings for the C++ wrapper, such that the code is directly available through both C++ and Python.

The project is called [FortWrap](https://github.com/thermotools/fortwrap), part of the [ThermoTools project](https://github.com/thermotools), and we would only be happy if anyone decides to use it.

If anyone wants to leave a PR for extended functionality, that would be awesome. Current functionality is already quite extensive, and the current development is mainly in assuring that the [`pybind11`](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) bindings are generated in a robust manner. My personal dream is that we can create a flexible, robust program to generate C++ wrappers, with bindings to python, for complex, object oriented Fortran code.